# Fine tuning of pre-trained convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As I read and searched about the **fine tuning of pre-trained network**, it is done in following two steps (in short):

1. freeze the hidden layer and unfreeze the fully connected layer and trained.
2. unfreeze both the layers and again train.

My questions are:

1. Whether it is enough to perform only first step?
2. If I preform only first step, is it not same as **network as a feature extractor** method?

(The network as a feature extractor method is, to extract the feature using pre-trained network and classify it using tradition machine learning classification algorithm).

If you want more information to clarify the question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your question...

First, you clearly imply a network with only 2 layers, which is rather (very) far from the way fine-tuning is actually used in practice nowadays.

Second, what exactly do you mean by "enough" in your first question (enough for what)?

---

In fact, there is enough overlapping between the notions of pre-trained models, feature extractors, and fine-tuning, and different people may even use the involved terms in not exactly the same ways. One approach, adopted by the Stanford [CNNs for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/) course, is to consider all these as special cases of something more general called **transfer learning**; here is a useful [excerpt](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) from the respective section of the aforementioned course, which arguably addresses the spirit (if not the letter) of your questions:

> The three major Transfer Learning scenarios look as follows:
>
> - **ConvNet as fixed feature extractor**. Take a ConvNet pretrained on ImageNet, remove the last fully-connected layer (this layer’s outputs are the 1000 class scores for a different task like ImageNet), then treat the rest of the ConvNet as a fixed feature extractor for the new dataset. In an AlexNet, this would compute a 4096-D vector for every image that contains the activations of the hidden layer immediately before the classifier. We call these features **CNN codes**. It is important for performance that these codes are ReLUd (i.e. thresholded at zero) if they were also thresholded during the training of the ConvNet on ImageNet (as is usually the case). Once you extract the 4096-D codes for all images, train a linear classifier (e.g. Linear SVM or Softmax classifier) for the new dataset.
> - **Fine-tuning the ConvNet**. The second strategy is to not only replace and retrain the classifier on top of the ConvNet on the new dataset, but to also fine-tune the weights of the pretrained network by continuing the backpropagation. It is possible to fine-tune all the layers of the ConvNet, or it’s possible to keep some of the earlier layers fixed (due to overfitting concerns) and only fine-tune some higher-level portion of the network. This is motivated by the observation that the earlier features of a ConvNet contain more generic features (e.g. edge detectors or color blob detectors) that should be useful to many tasks, but later layers of the ConvNet becomes progressively more specific to the details of the classes contained in the original dataset. In case of ImageNet for example, which contains many dog breeds, a significant portion of the representational power of the ConvNet may be devoted to features that are specific to differentiating between dog breeds.
> - **Pretrained models**. Since modern ConvNets take 2-3 weeks to train across multiple GPUs on ImageNet, it is common to see people release their final ConvNet checkpoints for the benefit of others who can use the networks for fine-tuning. For example, the Caffe library has a Model Zoo where people share their network weights.
>
> **When and how to fine-tune?** How do you decide what type of transfer learning you should perform on a new dataset? This is a function of several factors, but the two most important ones are the size of the new dataset (small or big), and its similarity to the original dataset (e.g. ImageNet-like in terms of the content of images and the classes, or very different, such as microscope images). Keeping in mind that ConvNet features are more generic in early layers and more original-dataset-specific in later layers, here are some common rules of thumb for navigating the 4 major scenarios:
>
> 1. *New dataset is small and similar to original dataset*. Since the data is small, it is not a good idea to fine-tune the ConvNet due to overfitting concerns. Since the data is similar to the original data, we expect higher-level features in the ConvNet to be relevant to this dataset as well. Hence, the best idea might be to train a linear classifier on the CNN codes.
> 2. *New dataset is large and similar to the original dataset*. Since we have more data, we can have more confidence that we won’t overfit if we were to try to fine-tune through the full network.
> 3. *New dataset is small but very different from the original dataset*. Since the data is small, it is likely best to only train a linear classifier. Since the dataset is very different, it might not be best to train the classifier form the top of the network, which contains more dataset-specific features. Instead, it might work better to train the SVM classifier from activations somewhere earlier in the network.
> 4. *New dataset is large and very different from the original dataset*. Since the dataset is very large, we may expect that we can afford to train a ConvNet from scratch. However, in practice it is very often still beneficial to initialize with weights from a pretrained model. In this case, we would have enough data and confidence to fine-tune through the entire network.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut, you explained it very nicely. But being specific to **Fine-tuning the ConvNet**,  if I replace the fully connected layer with new randomly initialized fully connected layer and then train it without fine-tuning the pre-trained weight, so will this fully connected layer work as a linear classifier as you mentioned in **ConvNet as fixed feature extractor**??

Comment: @Akhilesh Indeed; single FC layers are actually linear classifiers

Comment: Okay, that's what I was confused with. What if I'll use multiple FC layers? I guess it will be non-linear classifier, isn't it?

Comment: @Akhilesh yes - but I cannot see any reason why you couldn't use them